# Python: Calculating the area under a curve without knowing the function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am making a plot and I would like to calculate the area under the curves.
It don't need it done in same script but it would be nice if it was possible.
I am adding screen of data I am using to make them.

[image: The data I am using]

I have looked at some ways other did this but they always used a defined function. I have tried using trapz but it return nan as value. Also tried simpson but it also returned nan. Is it possible to get AUC with data like that using python? I will highly appreciate any help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as pe
from numpy import trapz


var = pd.read_excel(r'user\excel', sheet_name = 'sheet')

y = list(var['min'])
x1 = list(var['HRR1'])
x2 = list(var['HRR2'])
x3 = list(var['HRR3'])

plt.plot(y, x1, color='fuchsia', label='fire1', lw=2, path_effects=[pe.Stroke(linewidth=2, foreground='black'), pe.Normal()])
plt.fill_between(y, x1, color='fuchsia', alpha=0.5)
plt.annotate('Peak HRR1', xy=(17,8816), xytext=(8, 8500), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=1, headwidth=6))
area1 = trapz(y, x1)
print("THR1 =", area1)

plt.plot(y, x2, color='cyan', label='fire2', lw=2, path_effects=[pe.Stroke(linewidth=2, foreground='black'), pe.Normal()])
plt.fill_between(y, x2, color='cyan', alpha=0.5)
plt.annotate('Peak HRR2', xy=(6,6900), xytext=(8, 7500), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=1, headwidth=6))
area2 = trapz(y, x2)
print("THR2 =", area2)

plt.plot(y, x3, color='lime', label='fire3',  lw=2, path_effects=[pe.Stroke(linewidth=2, foreground='black'), pe.Normal()])
plt.fill_between(y, x3, color='lime', alpha=0.5)
plt.annotate('Peak HRR3', xy=(30,6000), xytext=(20, 8000), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=1, headwidth=6))
area3 = trapz(y, x3)
print("THR3 =", area3)

plt.legend(loc="upper right")

plt.xlim([0,40])
plt.ylim([0,10000])

plt.savefig('poglad.png', dpi=180, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Edit: I uploaded my excel file to google drive, here is link to it https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zZqVrxL_8zH1e2Y1DlobWhDXoT3HBKa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114585477469792344227&rtpof=true&sd=true

> E.g. in your case, the area area1 can be computed by
> area1 = integrate(var['min'], var['HRR1'])

I tried it but I got "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Edit2:

I changed code to: `area1 = integrate.simpson(y, x1)`
but the value given back is still NaN

Comment: Please insert the test data as text, not as image.  See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Your use of `np.trapz` is appropriate, so it is unclear why you're getting `NaN`. Please provide more information about your `var` DataFrame, such as sharing `var.describe()` and `var.info()`.

Comment: @jared I shared a link to data I am using

Comment: I'm looking for you to share pandas information, not for the actual data. Especially a good drive link; those share too much information.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def integrate(x, y):
    area = 0
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        w = x[i+1] - x[i]
        h = (y[i] + y[i+1]) / 2
        area += w * h
    return area
```

The function `integrate(x, y)` computes the area under the line given by concatenating each segment formed by connecting two adjacent points `(x[i], y[i])` and `(x[i+1], y[i+1])` and by that tries to approximate the underlying process `f` for which `f(x) = y`. It assumes that `x` is ordered.

Example:

```
n = 40
x = np.array(range(1, n + 1))
y = np.log2(x)
print(integrate(x, y))
```

prints

```
156.49807577673482
```

(where according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20of%20log2%28x%29%20fro%201%20to%2040) the area is 156.61). Of course, `np.trapz(y, x)` also does the trick (I assume that in your case it didn't work because 'min' is x and the 'HRR.' are the y, and not vice versa).

E.g. in your case, the area `area1` can be computed by

```
area1 = integrate(var['min'], var['HRR1'])
```

Comment: In Python the gymnastics using `minh` and `maxh` are not required, just use `(y[i] + y[i+1]) / 2`.

Comment: @MarkRansom you are of course very right about that - thanks for pointing this out! I have updated my answer correspondingly.

Comment: This is also a function in the numpy library: [np.trapz()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)